# Windows Docker NAT seems completely broken

Tags: docker, windows-10

I have a docker container that has the NAT mapping 0.0.0.0:9055->80/tcp.  From what I can tell, this should mean I can go to http://localhost:9055/ on my host machine, and it will be redirected to port 80 on the running Docker image.  However, when I try this it times out.

If I connect to the instance and run `docker exec -i 52806ceaf166 "ipconfig"` to see what the image's private IP is, I get 172.28.27.31.  When I try going to http://172.28.27.31/ on the host machine, it works!

I'd like to get the NAT mapping working since that's what all the tools assume works (such as Visual Studio, Kitematic, etc) and plus I don't want to have to worry about which containers use which IPs.  Is there a way to fix this?  Thanks!

PS: I'm new to Docker (just installed it today) so if any more info is needed (settings, versions, etc) just let me know how to get them and I'll add them to the post.

Comment: I've found this open bug, it seems to match your issue

: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1506

Comment: @SimoneZabberoni - Yea, seems related.  Unfortunately most of the steps to debug were for Linux based images.  I did try re-enabling HyperV and doing a full reboot - no luck.  Also, my Docker version is `18.03.1-ce`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking at the [Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/) I'm using, and I think this is what I'm running into:

[image]

This is a [known issue](http://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/issues/181) that'll be addressed in the near future.  The work around is fairly easy though.

**Update:** This was fixed in a recent Windows patch available through Windows Update.